# Wrong folder showing up in address bar?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created an MVC 3 website in Visual Studio 2010 and it works correctly on my station. However, when I upload it to GoDaddy in a sub domain of my website, the paths are not quite right.

For example: my subdomain name is "totallyyours" on "programguy.org". When an error occurs, the address bar is "totallyyours.programguy.org/totallyyours/error" where `error` is my custom error handler which it cannot find. Why is `totallyyours` appearing before `/error`?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Visual Studio configures web applications to be deployed to a virtual directory. This is why you have an extra folder.

1. Open the Properties pane for the web application.
2. Navigate to the
   Package/Publish Web tab
3. The value of IIS Web site/application should be DefaultWebSite